# Add UIButton in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a UIWebView which is already filled by my request (loadRequest).

I would like to add a UIButton in it. It's easy to write this simple code :

```
[self.myWebView loadRequest:request];
[self.myWebView addSubview:myButton];
```

However, it seems the UIButton won't scroll with the UIWebView's content. It stays fixed like a layer on top of the UIWebView. So when the user scrolls, the UIButton gets un-synchronized with the content.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Try adding the button to the web vew in the interface builder or you could reduce the frame size of the web view and add button to the view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can inject html markup such as 
    <a href='yourTag01'> <button>My Button </button> </a>
into the content of your UIWebview using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method.

To capture the click event and prevent it from reloading content of your webview use this delegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if(navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && [[request.URL absoluteString] isEqualToString: @"yourTag01"])
    {
        //your custom action code goes here
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be an interesting solution. I will try this tomorrow and let you know, thanks ;)

Comment: It worked, thanks :) My problem doing this method was the reloading of the UIWebView (using js-frame).

Comment: Can You please , Briefly  explain the concept which You have shown here ,. thank You

Comment: It would be even better if your button had an onclick handler which loaded a dummy url (yourTag01) in an invisible iframe, because with a link if you press  the button multiple times fast, it might not be recognized every time

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this in any sane straightforward way. You may want to reevaluate what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 5 you can directly access a UIWebView's scroll view, which is where you really want to add your button, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617955-scrollview. But I tend to agree with the previous commenters, you should probably be considering a different approach as mixing UIKit with a web view isn't really meant to work how you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with axiixc's comment, here is some code that you might use to place a button at the bottom of the webview.  By putting the positioning code in layout subviews you can handle rotation properly.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview{  
    if (!_button){
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        [button setTitle:@"Move All Blue Cards to Known" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"signin-button-blue-color"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
        [_webview.scrollView addSubview:button];
        _button = button;
    }

    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];

}


- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    float y = 0;
    CGRect originalRect = _webview.frame;
    _webview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, originalRect.size.width, 1); // Trick the webview into giving the right size for content
    CGSize contentSize = _webview.scrollView.contentSize;
    _webview.frame = originalRect;
    if (contentSize.height < _webview.frame.size.height){ // This keeps the button at the bottom of the webview, or at the bottom of the content, as needed.
        y = _webview.frame.size.height - 64; // 44 tall + 20 offset from the bottom
    } else {
        y = contentSize.height + 20;
    }

    _button.frame = CGRectMake(20, y, self.frame.size.width-40, 44); // 40/2 = 20 px on each side
    contentSize.height = CGRectGetMaxY(_button.frame)+20;
    _webview.scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;    
}
```