# Add UIButton in UIWebview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uiwebview

I want to add to add a button at the bottom of UIWebView.I went through several posts but didn't find any good answer.
Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this.
I want that button should be there when the user reaches the bottom of web view after scrolling.[used this link also by setting the button using html but can't that button action in iOS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346380/add-uibutton-in-a-uiwebview)

I am able to add button through HTML on UIWebView.

```
 NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><a href='yourTag01'> <button>Indian Statistics </button> </a></html>"];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

This delegate is getting called on clicking the button

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"%@",request.URL.absoluteString);
    if(navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && [[request.URL absoluteString] isEqualToString: @"yourTag01"])
    {
        NSLog(@"heloo");
        //your custom action code goes here
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

but it does't go in if condition.
Please help!!!

Comment: in console i get this "applewebdata://F62C9C78-9E8C-44B7-9916-5B765EAB765F/yourTag01
"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix what you are doing by using instead of this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
        NSLog(@"%@",request.URL.absoluteString);
        if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && [[request.URL absoluteString] isEqualToString: @"yourTag01"])
        {
            NSLog(@"heloo");
            //your custom action code goes here
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
}
```

Write this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
        NSLog(@"%@",request.URL.absoluteString);
        NSRange UrlInRequestRange = [[request.URL.absoluteString lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[@"yourTag01" lowercaseString]];
    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && UrlInRequestRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            NSLog(@"heloo");
            //your custom action code goes here
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
}
```

If you like trying a different way, Add your custom UIButton like this:

```
[webView.scrollView addSubview:btn];
```

Then to make sure the UIButton is at the end of the site thats viewed on your WebView use delegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGFloat contentHeight = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, contentHeight, btn.frame.size.width, btn.frame.size.height)];
}
```