# How to create a clickable button when it is below another view? (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

My `ViewController` contains `WebView` and invisible button over (or below) the `WebView`. (see image). I want that the button to be clickable. But(!) in the case  there are some links in the `WebView`, the links should be clicked, not the button.

How can I do it?

[image: example]

Similar issue discussed here:

[Add UIButton in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346380/add-uibutton-in-a-uiwebview)

However, in my case, I need links that are clickable also not be scrolling enabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add UIButton in a UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346380/add-uibutton-in-a-uiwebview)

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is to be able to still drag the `UIWebView` around while still being able to receive a button press on a certain part on the view, you don't need to place a button below it in order to achieve that.

`UIButton` can still be able to receive touch even if it is completely transparent.

```
yourButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This way the button would only receive the press and will not affect your dragging of the web view - it will ignore the dragging but respond only to the press.

Tested on a scrollable view with a clear `UIButton`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: no. it doesnt work such way. I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346380/add-uibutton-in-a-uiwebview.

Comment: i have added button to the scrollview of WebView. [webview.scrollview addSubview:button]